# Sampling from a very high dimensional Gaussian

Tags: sampling, covariance-matrix, gaussian-process, spatial, computational-statistics

I would like to a sample from a Gaussian $N(0,K)$ where $K$ is a kernel gram matrix, so that $K=[K_{ij}]$ with $K_{ij} = k(x_i,x_j)$ for some positive definite function $k$. The first issue is that the two-dimensional grid I am interested in evaluating $x_i,x_j$ over is very fine, so the size of $K$ is extremely large, and I cannot compute this matrix explicitly. Once we have this reprensetation of $K$, we need the cholesky decomposition in order to do the sampling.  I noticed that this question as [before](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/100301/55946), but the answers are a bit vague and don't point to any concrete references. Ideally, i'd like to do this in Python.

Comment: How many dimensions does this Gaussian have? Additional questions: 1. Have you tried *[copulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory))*? 2. have you tried dimensionality reduction already, so you sample the lower space? 3. In terms of Cholesky, have you looked at the $LDL^T$ too? I can be more numerically stable than the standard $LL^T$. 4. Instead of $LL^T$ the [Box–Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) might be another option that is usually slower than the Cholesky but is less affected by high dimensionality.

Comment: Many such (efficient) algorithms have been worked out, ranging from "Turning Bands" to sequential conditional simulation: see the literature on stochastic simulation related to Kriging.

Comment: @usεr11852 the grid is 1000x1000, so K is pxp with p=1M. Are the suggestions you make plausible without needing to explicitly compute the entire K matrix?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. They have sparse implementations. That said, Have you thought of binning the data in a 100 x 100 grid, for example?

Comment: @usεr11852 For my problem it needs to be 1000x1000 - so is it possible to use a copula approach without constructing the entire matrix K first?

Comment: I think it is impossible to do with vine copulas to be honest...

Comment: Copulas are useless here.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the suggestion, i'm reading about the turning bands method which seems like it will help. The references all seem to be quite old and I couldn't find a code implementation which was somewhat surprising

Comment: Turning bands turned out not to be as efficient and accurate as later methods based on conditional kriging.  There are some `R` packages, like `geoRglm`, that will do conditional simulation, but I haven't checked how well they will perform on a problem of this size.